# Limiting records returned by ExactTarget SOAP RetrieveRequest object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

I'm using the RetrieveRequest object in a SOAP request to retrieve all records in a Data Extension. This works well. Here's my request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[DataExtensionKey]</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerNo</Properties>
                <Properties>Title</Properties>
                <Properties>FirstName</Properties>
                <Properties>Surname</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The question is, can I include a filter in my request to **limit** the number of records returned, for example, rows 1-50? If so, what would that filter look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [RetrieveOptions](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/retrieveoptions/) Object you're able to limit the size of the request using `BatchSize`. I'm not 100% sure if it'll work as its description states

> Number of records to return in each batch as part of a Retrieve call.
> Reserved for future use.

This looks to be the only property that can limit the request.

Working SOAP Body:

```xml
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[DATAEXTENSIONKEY]</ObjectType>
            <Properties>TITLE</Properties>
            <Properties>DESCRIPTION</Properties>
            <Options>
                <BatchSize>2</BatchSize>
            </Options>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: You could test this with SOAP UI and determine if it works.  I'm not sure it does either, but it would be nice.

Comment: Nice, I'm assuming I should be nesting RetreiveOptions **inside** the RetrieveRequest element like this snippet. I've tried a few different scenarios and they return all rows :-(

       `<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
          <RetrieveRequest>
             <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[DataExtensionKey]</ObjectType>
             <Properties>CustomerNo</Properties>
             <RetrieveOptions>
              <BatchSize>3</BatchSize>
          </RetrieveOptions>
          </RetrieveRequest>
       </RetrieveRequestMsg>`

Comment: @EliotHarper I've included a tested and working body for you to use in your API Call.

Comment: @EliotHarper - if you can confirm, switch your answer here. Nice work Sandeep.

Comment: This is fantastic, **thank you** so much for adding this support! I just added `<Options> <BatchSize>3</BatchSize> </Options>` inside my `RetrieveRequest` and it works!

Comment: Making a mental note of this.  Not sure when it was implemented,  but we all should rejoice.

Comment: This does not appear to work using the SSJS API functions.