# PHP Fuel API Attributes not updated

Tags: fuel-sdk, fuel, sdk

I'm updating an existing subscriber, however I cannot get custom Data extensions updated. Here is my code

```
$client = new ET_Client( );

$subscriberWrapper = new ET_Subscriber();

$subscriberWrapper->authStub = $client;
$subscriberWrapper->filter = array('Property' => 'EmailAddress','SimpleOperator' => 'equals','Value' => $data['Email']);
$subscriberWrapper->props = array("ID", "SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress"); //Attributes are loaded if exactly these properties are requested http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/34956
$subscribers = $subscriberWrapper->get();

$subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
$subscriber->authStub = $client;

$subscriber->props['SubscriberKey'] = $subscribers->results[$foundHousehold]->SubscriberKey;
$subscriber->props['Status'] = 'Active';

$action = 'patch';

$converter = new SourceConverter();

$attributes = array();
foreach ($attributeMap as $source => $attributeName){
    if (method_exists( $converter, $source ) ){
        $value = $converter->$source($data);
    }else{
        $value = $data[$source];
    }

    if (!$attributeName || !$value) continue;
    $attributes[] = array(
        'Name' => $attributeName,
        'Value' => $value
    );

}
//Attribute are set as expected, no empty name, no empty value

//I found that if I leave these out I get 
//PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Name' property
//PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Value' property
$attributes['Name'] = 'abc';
$attributes['Value'] = 'abc';

$subscriber->props['Attributes'] = $attributes;

$list = new ET_List();
$list->ID = $mylistID;
$list->authStub = $client;
$subscriber->Lists[] = $list;

$result = $subscriber->$action();
echo "========= REQUEST ==========" . PHP_EOL;
print htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest());

die();
```

The resulting output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:UpdateRequest>
            <ns1:Options/>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>Time Zone Offset</ns1:Name>                   
                     <ns1:Value>+10:00</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>FirstName</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>John</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>LastName</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>Smith</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>Country</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>AU</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>Country Name</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>Australia</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>State</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>Adamstown Heights</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>Zipcode</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>2289</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Attributes>
                <ns1:Attributes>
                     <ns1:Name>Address1</ns1:Name>
                     <ns1:Value>49 Lucas Crescent</ns1:Value>
              </ns1:Attributes> 
              <ns1:SubscriberKey>zzz1517@thebrandpool.com.au</ns1:SubscriberKey>

                 <ns1:Status>Active</ns1:Status>
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:UpdateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

There is no error, but Attributes are not updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The format of how data is submitted is correct, however the way I transferred timezone offset was incorrect and this could be found in the $result object. So there was indeed an error, but the above code can otherwise be used for updating of attributes.